# FFMPEG settings for unsharpmasking with and without upsampling

Tags: ffmpeg

I am tasked with trying to 'improve' the quality of video from a point and shoot camera. I was considering perhaps up-sampling and then applying some unsharp masking.

Can any FFMPEG experts suggest some starting settings for unsharp masking, both with, and without up-sampling (say from 320X180 to 720P 1280X720)?

Comment: use the hqdn3d filter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [unsharp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#unsharp) filters in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "scale=1280:-1:flags=lanczos,unsharp=5:5:1.0:5:5:0.0" output
```

- The `-1` in the scale filter will automatically choose the correct height to preserve aspect ratio.
- You can change the scale algorithm with the `flags` option in the scale filter. For upsampling `lanczos` is worth trying. Default is `bicubic` (if using `-vf`/`-filter:v`) or `bilinear` (if using `-filter_complex`). See the full list of algorithms with `ffmpeg -h filter=scale` (listed under `-sws_flags`) or at [FFmpeg Scaler Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html#toc-Scaler-Options).
- This example uses the default `unsharp` settings: `5:5:1.0:5:5:0.0`, which were included for demonstration purposes. These values allow you to sharpen or blur chroma and/or luma. See the [unsharp filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#unsharp) more examples.

Comment: `Option filter:v (set stream filtergraph) cannot be applied to input`

Comment: @e-info128 Order of options matters. You're attempting to apply filters to the input, but filtering is an output option. `ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the `lanczos` tip, I was wondering why videos scaled with ffmpeg had worse quality than when I fullscreen them in the player. So that was because ffmpeg uses the [cheap](https://goo.gl/images/bFhZLM) `bicubic` scaling by default...